# How to implement a deployment-specific pluggable architecture in a single code base

Tags: symfony

I know this is somewhat subjective, but Symfony being as it is there must be a feature specifically designed for this purpose.

Here are the main factors of what I need to do:

- The system will be deployed separately for multiple customers (probably just a handful. scale isn't a big concern).
- Each deployment has a small amount of highly bespoke functionality specific to the customer. This could be *anything*.
- I want to maintain a single, common codebase (including composer.json). The only file I really want outside of our repo is `parameters.yml`.

My current thinking involves a custom bundle for every customer - hooking into them using custom Symfony events, fired from the common parts of the system. But ...

Symfony bundles aren't designed to be dynamically registered. They're baked into our core system so I can't switch them on and off for individual customers without forking/splitting the codebase. This means not only a bloated Kernel, but also events would be received by all bundles in all deployments.

I can get around that last point by namespacing the events with a configuration parameter. Even if I can live with redundant bundles in the Kernel, this whole approach seems too hard to be correct.

What is the proper way to support a "pluggable" architecture than I can hook into from the core system without splitting my codebase?

Comment: Use Capifony: http://capifony.org, it's a very powerful open source tool for running scripts on multiple servers. It’s primary use is for easily deploying applications, it’s pretty simple to customize it to deploy other types of applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use multiple app-directories. Then you can turn on/off bundles for each client since each client has it's own AppKernel.php and then you can create a separate /web/app.php for each client and point it to the currect app-directory.

You can then use mod-rewrite in Apache to point each client's subdomain or something to the right app.php file

Comment: interesting idea, thanks. I hadn't thought of this so will look into it. I guess it means duplicating a fair amount of files, but that might not be so bad.

Comment: Yea, it depends on how dynamic it needs to be, but for something like this where you have many different features, I've seen this approach work. The responsible thing to do then would be to use continuous integration and have each and every one of your client kernels tested, both to make sure their features are working and to make sure their features don't conflict with some of the core stuff :).